# Local Notification : repeat "permanently" with arbitrary alert message and incremental badge

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, uilocalnotification

I am working on the alert project which daily alerts the varying message and daily increments the badge. What I want to do is something like below.

---

Day1 : alert "January 1st", Badge = 1

Day2 : alert "January 2nd", Badge = 2

Day3 : alert "January 3rd", Badge = 3

Day4 : alert "January 4th", Badge = 4

::::

Day365 : alert "December 31st", Badge = 365

---

```
localnotification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit
```

can repeat every day, but it will only repeats registered static notification. i.e always same alert message of "January 1st" and badge will stay "1" every time notification pops up.

I can register each separate local notifications but it is limited to register only 64 notifications, and it will not keep alerting after 64 times of alerts if the user does not launch the application at all.

Does any one know how to setup permanent snooze notification with arbitrary alert message and incremental badge **without having launch the application**? - If anyone knows workaround to do the same/similar thing will be great too!

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule a UILocalNotification to repeat it self, for example every day, week, month, year.... But it will be the same notification every time.

There is noway to make it snooze, you will need to set a second notification to make it look like the snooze time is past. Just cancel that notification when the user does open your app with the first notification.

The badge number is not incremented, it a stack number. You can not make it increment other then setting it when your app startup.

Comment: Hello Rckoenes, Thanks a lot for your prompt reply! I understood that there is no straight forward way to set things up, but can you imagine any workaround to implement what I want to do? - Thank you so much.

Comment: No, there is not way, you just have 64 notifications that's it. You could setup new notification every week. But if the user does not start your app every week it won't work. You could switch to Push notifications but you will need a server.